# Pundit with has_one relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pundit

I have two models: User and Employer. Users have one Employer. I am using pundit for authorization. With a has_one relationship how would I authorize the new and create actions? Ideally the user couldn't even go to the form if they have already submitted it.

I could do this in the controller:

```
def new
  unless current_user.employer.present?
    @employer = Employer.new
  else
    flash[:error] = "Record already exists"
    redirect_back(fallback_location: current_user)
  end
end
```

But I would prefer to do something in pundit.

```
class EmployerPolicy < ApplicationPolicy

  def create?
   # Do I check is the @user has an employer before submission?
  end

  def new?
   # Or do I check if the @user has a record before they get here?
  end
end
```

Any insight would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: so what exactly do you want to authorize/prevent?

Comment: Are you sure that a `has_one` relation (and its opposite `belongs_to`) is the right choice? One user has on employer _and_ an employer belongs to a user (just a 1:1 relation)?

Comment: @Cyzanfar. I only want the user to go the the new employer form and submit one time.

Comment: @spickermann each user should have their own employer. I am not interested if multiple users share the same employer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving this problem without pundit.

In the `User` model I build the default association and child (`Employer`) on create. Then in the `routes.rb` under the resources for employer I exclude create and new.